# find the maximum in a column, but only when two other columns match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help in PostgreSQL.
I have two tables

1. Predicton - predicts future disasters and casualties for each city.
2. Measures fits the type of damage control providers for each type of disaster (incl. cost and percent of "averted casualties")

[image: tables]

Each disaster and provider combination has an amount of averted casualties (the percent from measures * amount of predicted casualties for that disaster*0.01).

For each combination of city and disaster, I need to find two providers that
1) their combined cost is less than a million
2) have the biggest amount of combined averted casualties.

My work and product so far

```
select o1.cname, o1.etype, o1.provider as provider1, o2.provider as provider2, (o1.averted + o2.averted) averted_casualties
from (select cname, m.etype, provider, mcost, (percent*Casualties*0.01)averted
from measures m, prediction p
where (m.etype = p.etype)) as o1, (select cname, m.etype, provider, mcost, (percent*Casualties*0.01)averted
from measures m, prediction p
where (m.etype = p.etype)) as o2
where (o1.cname = o2.cname) and (o1.etype = o2.etype) and (o1.provider < o2.provider) and (o1.mcost + o2.mcost < 1000000)
```

[image: outcome of current work]

How do I change this query so It Will show me the best averted_casualties for each city/disaster combo (not just max of all table, max for each combo)
This is the desired outcome:

[image: desired]

P.S. I'm not allowed to use ordering, views or functions.

Comment: That's what I was asked to. It's part of a pre-interview for a job. Only posted it here because I'm lost. would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, construct all pairs of providers and do the casualty and cost calculation:

```
  select p.*, m1.provider as provider_1, m2.provider as provider_2,
         p.casualties * (1 - m1.percent / 100.0) * (1 - m2.percent / 100.0) as net_casualties,
         (m1.mcost + m2.mcost) as total_cost
  from measures m1 join
       measures m2
       on m1.etype = m2.etype and m1.provide < m2.provider join
       prediction p
       on m1.etype = p.etype;
```

Then, apply your conditions.  Normally, you would use window functions, but since ordering isn't allowed for this exercise, you want to use a subquery:

```
with pairs as (
      select p.*, m1.provider as provider_1, m2.provider as provider_2,
             p.casualties * (1 - m1.percent / 100.0) * (1 - m2.percent / 100.0) as net_casualties,
             (m1.mcost + m2.mcost) as total_cost
      from measures m1 join
           measures m2
           on m1.etype = m2.etype and m1.provide < m2.provider join
           prediction p
           on m1.etype = p.etype;
    )
select p.*
from pairs p
where p.total_cost < 1000000 and
      p.net_casualties = (select min(p2.net_casualties)
                          from pairs p2
                          where p2.city = p.city and p2.etype = p.etype and
                                p2.total_cost < 1000000
                         );
```

The biggest number of averted casualties results in the smallest number of net casualties.  They are the same thing.

As for your attempted solution.  Just seeing the `,` in the `from` clause tells me that you need to study up on `join`.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use proper, explicit, **standard** `join` syntax.

Your repeated subqueries also suggest that you need to learn about CTEs.

Comment: Thanks for the help but you misunderstood the question. I need to find the two providers that give the biggest amount of "Averted casualties", not actual casualties that happen in the disaster.

Comment: @JohnKale . . . Not at all.  The biggest number of averted casualties is the smallest number of net casualties.

Comment: Ah okay.
Thanks for the help. Now I understand everything.
Would apperciate if you point out any other thing in my code that was too complicated/ redunant/not standard/ could have been solved easier with another expression.